# UWP Passkeys Windows 23h2

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Microsoft has added a new PassKeys feature in its latest 23h2 update. I can't find any documentation anywhere for UWP apps to implement this new feature.
My application simply implements authorization via Windows Hello, but in the current situation it does not add the key to the PassKeys table. I need to change the implementation to the current one with adding keys to passkeys, but how can I do this in C#?